# Ignore Records that have same value of same property in the IEnumerable C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to take all records that have different value of bugetType property and Ignore all records that have the same value for bugetType property...How to do that?

```
FreelancerProjectsNoduplication = _context.FreelancerProjects.GroupBy(f => f.BugetType).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g),
```

Comment: Try `.GroupBy(f => f.BugetType).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g)`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen are you sure that  `g.Count() > 1` (take the ones which type repeat) not `g.Count() == 1` (take the ones which type is not repeated)  also I think that he means `.GroupBy(f => f.BugetType).Select(g=>g.First())` but the question is unclear

Comment: I have Used the two ways (g>1) and (g==1)  the first one (g>1) takes all records and the second takes nothing

Comment: I saw that loophole in the comment I provided but I want him to see it too so that it clarifies the language used. I've commented with a literal example, but I too doubt this is what he wants.

Comment: If you used the code from my comment, and it still returned all the rows, that means you have different BugetType values.

Comment: all records have the same value for "BugetType" Property

Comment: note the the "BugetType" property is an enum

Answer (score 1):

The `.Distinct` method has an overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` as first parameter. For example you if you wanted to perform a `.Distinct` operation on a collection of `SomeClass` based on the `SomeInt` property you could use an `IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>` implemented like `SomeClassComparer` :

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeClass>
{
    public bool Equals(SomeClass x, SomeClass y)
    {
        return x.SomeInt.Equals(y.SomeInt);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SomeClass obj)
    {
        return obj.SomeInt.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can do `CollectionOfSomeClass.Distinct(new SomeClassComparer());`

More infos about `IEqualityComparer<T>` can be found  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8)